# Android studio project migration

Tags: android, migration, project

I have an Android Studio-based project installed under Windows on one computer, and I want to migrate it to my Linux-based installation of Android Studio. I don't mind recompiling and/or rebuilding. I was thinking that if I have two installations of Android studio, I would only have to move the entire directory under ./Projects, but when I do this, I get error messages about missing dependencies and other Gradle-related error messages.  Thank You :-)

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to make this a comment but why not just use a GIT repository? Using that should help you with that problem.